# Make a function like window.confirm which return true or false based on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a function like window.confirm which can be used like this :

```
if (I.confirmDialog.open("Do you really want to Cancel")) {
    // do this
} 
else { 
    //  do this 
}
```

I am writing the pop-up function like this :

```
I.confirmDialog = {

  open: function(confirmMsg) {

    var $modal = I.modals.new("small confirm-dialog");
    $modal.find("h1").text(confirmMsg);
    $modal.append("<div class=\"action-wraper\"><a class=\"action-yes\" href=\"javascript:void(0);\">Yes</a><a class=\"action-no\"href=\"javascript:void(0);\">No</a></div>");
    I.modals.open($modal);
    $modal.find(".action-yes").click(function() { I.modals.close(); /* return true will not work*/ });
    $modal.find(".action-no").click(function() { I.modals.close(); /* return false will not work*/ });

  }

};
```

But the problem is I am unable to return true or false from the `I.confirmDialog.open()`. execution of `I.confirmDialog.open()` function doesn't wait for button click and the return from click callback doesn't affect  the return value of `I.confirmDialog.open()`.

I would like to know how window.confirm is written if possible

Comment: jQuery Promises https://api.jquery.com/promise/

Comment: As far as I know it is not possible to create a modal dialog from javascript. Basically you have to rely on the click event callbacks. Also a transparent full-page div could be used to simulate the modal behavior preventing user interaction with the other page elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you have here is that the modal being actioned is effectively asynchronous (as you have to wait for user input), so you cannot `return` anything.

Instead, provide some callback functions to the method which can be called in the required events:

```
I.confirmDialog = {
    open: function(confirmMsg, yesCallback, noCallback) {
        var $modal = I.modals.new("small confirm-dialog");
        $modal.append('<div class="action-wraper"><a class="action-yes" href="#">Yes</a><a class="action-no" href="#">No</a></div>').find("h1").text(confirmMsg);

        I.modals.open($modal);

        $modal.find(".action-yes").click(function(e) { 
            e.preventDefault();
            I.modals.close(); 
            yesCallback && yesCallback();
        });

        $modal.find(".action-no").click(function(e) { 
            e.preventDefault();
            I.modals.close(); 
            noCallback && noCallback();
        });
    }
};
```

You would then call it like this:

```
I.confirmDialog.open("Do you really want to Cancel", function() {
    console.log('you clicked YES');
}, function() {
    console.log('you clicked NO');
});
```